# Python: "importing" input arguments

Tags: python, input, arguments, argparse

I have two python scripts `A` and `B`, both with a main and with different input arguments (I use `argparse`). I launch them normally with:

```
$ python A.py --paramA1 valA1 --paramA2 valA2
$ python B.py --paramB1 valB1 --paramB2 valB2
```

I'd like  to be able to call `B` from within `A` and to specify `B`'s parameters when launching `A`. In short, I want to call `A` with `A`'s parameters and `B`'s parameters. Here's what it should look like from the outside:

```
$ python A.py --paramA1 valA1 --paramA2 valA2 --paramB1 valB1 --paramB2 valB2
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this than copying and pasting `B`'s `argparse` code into `A` and then calling `B` on them?

**EDIT**: To simplify things, here's some example code:

A.py:

```
import argparse
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Args for A.py")
    parser.add_argument("--param1A", type=int)
    parser.add_argument("--param2A", type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    valA1 = args.param1A
    valA2 = args.param2A
    ...
    return 0
```

B.py:

```
import argparse
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Args for B.py")
    parser.add_argument("--param1B", type=int)
    parser.add_argument("--param2B", type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    valA1 = args.param1B
    valA2 = args.param2B
    ...
    return 0
```

What exactly would the suggested `C.py`, which includes arguments for both `A.py` and `B.py` look like? And what would `A.py` and `B.py` look like then?

***EDIT 2:*** I forgot to mention that one of the parameters of `B.py` has to be created in `A.py`, so the order of execution is `A` then `B`, and `A` has to be able to pass a parameter to `B`.

Comment: I think an elegant solution here would be to wrap the argument parsing in to a third file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a module `C.py` which contains the common `argparse` logic and is imported by both A and B.

When calling B from A, you could also pass B the already parsed args. I mean, both A and B should have something like a `main` function  which takes the already parsed args, therefore not having to do the parsing twice.

C.py

```
import argparse

def create_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Args for B.py")
    parser.add_argument("--param1B", type=int)
    parser.add_argument("--param2B", type=int)
    return parser
```

B.py

```
import argparse
import sys
import C

def main(args):
    valB1 = args.param1B
    valB2 = args.param2B
    # do stuff
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = C.create_parser()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    sys.exit(main(args))
```

A.py

```
import argparse
import sys
import C
import B

def main(args):
    valA1 = args.param1A
    valA2 = args.param2A
    # do stuff
    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = C.create_parser()
    parser.add_argument("--param1A", type=int)
    parser.add_argument("--param2A", type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    B.main(args)
    sys.exit(main(args))
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you give me an example based on the code provided in my (now) edited question? I don't understand how I should modify A.py and B.py if I write this new module C.py.

Comment: You can even bypass C altogether and put create_parser in B, which is then imported by A

Comment: Thanks a lot! One small thing: is it correct when under `if __name__ == '__main__':` you write `return main(args)`? I am getting `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`, which points to the fact that I am not inside a function in that block of code. Should I just do `sys.exit(main(args))`?

Comment: Ahh, missed that. Indeed, sys.exit should be used. I'll edit the response.

Comment: I forgot to mention one important detail: in `A.py` I create what will be one of the input parameters of `B.py`. How can I pass it to `B`, in the code you wrote?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question. After you're creating 'args' you then pass it to B.main(args). Even though args might contain A's arguments as well, B.main will only look at those it needs.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to make it clear: in `A` I save some results to a file `file.txt`, and `B` takes the path to that file as one of its input arguments. I should have said this from the beginning, sorry.

Comment: That makes things quite different. My overall feeling is that you're trying to make things more complicated that they should be. I would rather go for the Unix philosophy and try to build short, simple scripts, with clear interfaces, which can then be chained together through pipes and/or xargs.

Answer (score 1):

I think what @Ioan Alexandru Cucu described is something like the following:

```
import argparse

class A():
    __init__(self, param1A, param2A, param1B=None, param2B=None):
        if(param1B and param2B):
            myB = B(param1B, param2B)
        #Do processing here ...
        return 0


class B():
    __init__(self, param1B, param2B):
        #Do processing here ...
        return 0

if(__name__ == '__main__'):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Args for A and/or B")

    parser.add_argument("--param1A", type=int)
    parser.add_argument("--param2A", type=int)

    parser.add_argument("--param1B", type=int)
    parser.add_argument("--param2B", type=int)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if(args.param1A and args.param2A and args.param1B and args.param2B):
        A(args.param1A, args.param2A, args.param1B, args.param2B)
    if(args.param1A and args.param2A):
        A(args.param1A, args.param2A)
    elif(args.param1B and args.param2B):
        B(args.param1B, args.param2B)
```

Instead of having multiple classes in one module you can have multiple modules with the different classes in them.